# Can i use DataGridViewComboBoxColumn to display a list of class objects?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridviewcombobox

I am trying to populate a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` with a list of class objects ( With `ToString` overloaded). This method has worked perfectly for me for regular combo boxes. However once I load the `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` into the `dataGridView` it throws an error every time I click away from the datagrid.

Here is the error.

```
The Following Exception Occurred in the DataGridView:
System.ArgumentException: DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid.
To replace this default dialog please handle the DataError event.
```

And this is the code that is executed prior to the error dialogs:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

List<mclass> MObjects = new List<mclass>();

DataGridViewComboBoxColumn objcolumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();

objcolumn.DataSource = MObjects;

objcolumn.ValueType = typeof(mclass);

dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

dataGridView1.Columns.Add(objcolumn);
```

Now between the error messages, the columns work fine. I can select the object from the list perfectly. How do I get this error to go away and leave my working combo column in peace? Have I missed anything? Or do I need to find a way to remove that error message?

I tried adding in this line after some research:

```
dt.Columns.Add("OBJList", typeof(mclass));
```

However this makes the same exception, much longer ( I have omitted most of it, available on request ):

```
The following exception occurred in the DataGridView:
System.FormatException: Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'Namespace.mobject'. --->      
    System.InvalidCastException: Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'Namespace.mobject'.
```

Comment: Might your problem be caused by the ComboBoxStyle being DropDown, which means the text is editable.  Try changing the style to DropDownList, which means the text is not editable.

Comment: The text is currently un-editable. I believe its as you suggested by default.

Comment: Curiouser and Curiouser. Apparently this is a common issue with the ComboBoxColumn for any data type, even strings.

Comment: I have tried overloading the error handling for the datagridview, with no results, here is the code:

    private void DataGridView1_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs anError)
            {

    anError.Cancel = true;
             
            }

This still isn't working, despite this correctly cancelling the error to my mind. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your `ValueType` must be `string`.
The `typeof` part should be the method to extract the value, probably inside your `ToString()`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? Should I create a method that returns a string in the mclass class? and then have the type = that method?